# QGIS 3.22 Labeling Previews show expected result, but is not shown on canvas

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-custom-function

I created a function to label rasters whose boundaries are the same but represent different features. To do so, I have a set of rasters and a point vector layer with one field representing each of these raster layers.

However, despite the preview showing the right value, the canvas won't show any label.

The function is as follows:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *


@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])

def raster_label(feature, parent) -> str:

    field_list = ['field_a',
                  'field_b',
                  'field_c',
                  'field_d']
    
    raster_layer_name_list = ["LAYER_A",
                              "LAYER_B",
                              "LAYER_C",
                              "LAYER_D"]
    
    field_to_show = ""

    # create a list with all layers in the canvas
    layers_list = []
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    def get_group_layers(group):
        for child in root.children():
            if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                get_group_layers(child)
            elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
                layers_list.append(child.name())
    
    for child in root.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
            get_group_layers(child)
        elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            layers_list.append(child.name())
    
    # iterate over all items in layer list ...
    for item in range(0, len(layers_list)):
        l = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(layers_list[item])
        node = root.findLayer(l[-1])
        # then identify if the layer is checked ...
        if node.isVisible() == True:
            # to compare against the raster_layer_name_list ...
            for raster in range(0, len(raster_layer_name_list)):
                # returning then the corresponding field
                # the second condi
                if l[0].name() == raster_layer_name_list[raster]:
                    field_to_show = field_list[raster]
                    break
            if field_to_show != "":
                break
        if field_to_show != "":
            break
    
    if field_to_show == "":
        return field_to_show
    else:
        return round(feature[field_to_show], 1)
```

The workaround I found is to use this expression: `eval(raster_label())`. By using this expression, the expected results show both in the preview and on canvas.

Does somebody have an idea about why it is happening?